# Access Query SQL IIf Statement with OR

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM BOM INNER JOIN Parts ON BOM.PartID = Parts.PartID
WHERE (((BOM.PUMP_CODE) Like (IIf([Forms]![frmSelector]![tbMotor]>0 And
     [Forms]![frmSelector]![tbShaft]>0,"MOTOR" Or "SHAFT",IIf([Forms]![frmSelector]![tbMotor]>0,"MOTOR","SHAFT")))))
ORDER BY BOM.BOM_INDEX;
```

In the first IIF statement, I cannot get the query to return any records. I want it to return all records with either "MOTOR" or "SHAFT" in the PUMP_CODE field when both referenced objects are > 0. Even though both objects are greater than 0, it still does not return any records. The latter IIF statement is working just fine however. Is there a problem with this query?

Comment: In the first IIF statement your true expression, "MOTOR" Or "SHAFT" isn't valid. You need only the true portion of the initial IIF here as the false is part of the second IIF expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `"MOTOR" Or "SHAFT"` is wrong. The `or` of two strings is evaluated FIRST, and the result of that `or` is what gets used by `iif()`.

That means you're effectively doing

```
IIF(..., true, ...)
```

or whatever it is that access `or`s two strings into.

In any pretty much ANY programming language, you cannot do

```
if (x == "a" or "b")
```

because it'll be executed as

```
if (x == ("a" or "b")) -> if (x == (result))
```

You need to do

```
if (x == "a") OR (x == "b")
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying about the programming theory, but I'm not sure I understand how to resolve it. I tried using parentheses as follows: 

'Like (IIf([Forms]![frmSelector]![tbMotor]>0 And [Forms]![frmSelector]![tbShaft]>0,(([BOM].[PUMP_CODE])="MOTOR") Or (([BOM].[PUMP_CODE])="SHAFT"),IIf([Forms]![frmSelector]![tbMotor]>0,"MOTOR","SHAFT")))'. The result is the same,

Comment: again that won't work. you're still doing an `or` inside there, which means that the RESULT of the `or` is what's returned. `iif(condition, truevalue, falsevalue)`. you need to do your testing in the `condition` section. doing it in the truevalue/falsevalue sections RETURNS the results of your `or` comparison, not the values themselves. e.g. `iif(tbmotor > 0 OR pump_code='motor' OR pump_code='shaft', something, whatever)`

Comment: OK, I understand that part. I wasn't attempting to do any testing in the iif(...,true....) though. The testing is already being done by the two ">0" checks under iff(testing,...,...). Because both of these criteria have passed, I then want the query to return records with "SHAFT" in the PUMP_CODE field AND ALSO records with "MOTOR" in the field PUMP_CODE. Is there another way to structure the query to accomplish this?

Comment: embed another iif: `iif(..., iif(pump_code='motor', 'motor', iif(pump_code='shaft', 'shaft', '')))`. which gets EXTREMELY ugly very quick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IN Clause instead of LIKE and change your IIF to put both together if both settings are greater than 0, otherwise use your working clause.

I also added escaped double quotes to enclose the pair, and added to single items in case you ever use items that have spaces in them

```
SELECT * FROM BOM INNER JOIN Parts ON BOM.PartID = Parts.PartID
WHERE BOM.PUMP_CODE IN (
IIf([Forms]![frmSelector]![tbMotor]>0 And [Forms]![frmSelector]![tbShaft]>0, """MOTOR"",""SHAFT""",
     IIf([Forms]![frmSelector]![tbMotor]>0,""MOTOR"",""SHAFT"")))     
ORDER BY BOM.BOM_INDEX;
```